# Connect mongodb to google data studio

Tags: mongodb, google-sheets, looker-studio

I'm trying to connect MongoDB to Google Data Studio. As there isn't an official connector, I tried to connect MongoDB to Google Spreadsheet with the function `importdata(url)`, but the rows that I can import are limited.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: As you mentioned, a MongoDB connector is not implemented at the moment. However, you may vote up this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/70779807) for more visibility to the product team. Using the importdata(url) for a spreadsheet is limited to 50 calls on a single spreadsheet. I assume you are importing a CSV file. Is that right ? Did you consider [importing  the file directly](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7333350) or using [google cloud storage](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7511998)?

Comment: How about use Google BigQuery? Load your data from MongoDB to BigQuery, and then connect Google BigQuery to Google Data Studio. The advantage using Google BigQuery is you can use use it just like a "database". You can create views and link Google BigQuery Views to Data Studio. You can run the scheduled BigQuery Queries and generate the new updated data for the DataStudio.

Comment: You can use mongoDB Stitch. try following the following guide.
https://www.stitchdata.com/integrations/mongodb/google-data-studio/

Comment: I ended up to use stitch, it's really amazing, but it's not free.

Answer (score 1):

Now you can import data from a MongoDB collection into [Looker BI Platform](https://www.looker.com/) - formerly known as Google Data Studio with [MongoDB Connector for BI](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center/bi-connector/releases). Essentially, the MongoDB Connector for BI translates queries and data (adapter) to allow you to create queries with SQL. This connector stores no data, and purely serves as a bridge.

You would need a MongoDB Atlas M10+ instance with [the BI Connector enabled](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/atlas-bi-connector/) and a Looker account. The reason you would need a dedicated Atlas M10 instance or greater, is because the BI Connector is a powerful tool which performs operations which may be CPU/Memory intensive.

To connect Looker to your Atlas cluster, in the Looker account  go to Admin settings to create a new connection. Select `MongoBI` in the Dialect menu.

See also:

- [MongoDB: Connect from Looker](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/bi-connector/current/connect/looker/)
- [MongoDB: Connect via BI Connector for Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/bi-connection/)
- [Google: Connecting Looker to your database](https://cloud.google.com/looker/docs/connecting-to-your-db)

Comment: As your solution require payment, if you add also stichdata tool I'll set your answer as correct